# ''cURL is not installed on this server'' after updating to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, php, curl

I've recently updated my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 and then from 18.04 to 20.04. Now two plugins on my Wordpress site give me these errors:

1- OneSignal Push: `cURL is not installed on this server. cURL is required to send notifications. Please make sure cURL is installed on your server before continuing.`

2- `Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: curl`

I’ve tried every related solution on the internet so far but could not solve this problem yet. I ran `sudo apt-get install curl`, but nothing has changed. I also got this: `curl is already the newest version (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2)`.

Output of `apt-cache policy php7.4-curl`

```
php7.4-curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4
  Version table:
     7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.4.3-4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Getting this: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-curl : Depends: php7.4-curl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I didn't get what you're saying. What should I exactly I do?

Comment: It's a server on DigitalOcean, I am using Putty.

Comment: Did that, what's next? still get same error while trying sudo apt install php-curl

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: output: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-curl : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4) but 7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed

Comment: I think it is about ''There are probably some remnants from the previous PHP installations of previous Ubuntu versions'' as mentioned below. Because it happened after the update.

Comment: That is probably what needs to be done then.  I have removed all my previous comments as they hate extended chats in the comments section.  I hope you get it fixed.  =)

Answer (score 4):

The package [curl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/curl) contains the command line interface, basically the command `curl`. But WordPress (including its plugins) are developed in PHP, and PHP can't just use the command line version of cURL. PHP needs the corresponding [extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for that.

In Ubuntu, several PHP extensions are packaged as their own packages, like [php-mysql](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php/php-mysql) or [php-imagick](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php/php-imagick). In the case of cURL, that extension package would be [php-curl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php-curl). That's probably what you're missing.

As a side note: `php-curl` doesn't itself contain the PHP extension. This is provided by a package for the respective PHP version that `php-curl` depends on. So, if you install `php-curl` for example on Ubuntu 20.04, it will also install [php7.4-curl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php7.4-curl), because Ubuntu 20.04 comes with PHP 7.4.

Comment: I get this: The following packages have unmet dependencies: php-curl : Depends: php7.4-curl but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: @rem3on: There are probably some remnants from the previous PHP installations of previous Ubuntu versions. You may want to check which packages that contain `curl` are (still) installed: `dpkg -l '*curl*' | grep ^ii`. Then you can go from there.

Comment: ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2                      amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii  libcurl4:amd64        7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2                      amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
ii  python3-pycurl        7.43.0.2-1ubuntu5                      amd64        Python bindings to libcurl (Python 3)

Comment: The output is above. It's related to remnants I believe but I don't know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: @rem3on Judging by one of your comments to the question, there's an older version of `php7.4-common` still installed. To install `php-curl`, you need to also install `php7.4-curl`. That in turn depends on `php7.4-common`. In Ubuntu 20.04, `php7.4-common` corresponds to `7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4`. But a "competing" `php7.4-common` is already installed, being `7.4.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`. This looks like PHP 7.4 for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely seems to be the problem. Could you give me step by step commands to fix this? Probably need to delete smt and reinstall? Unfortunately I don't understand this so I don't want to mess this up myself.

Comment: @rem3on You may want to check the exact name of the currently installed version of `php7.4-common`, remove that and then try to install `php-curl` again. Maybe that solves everything, maybe there are additional problems. But, honestly, I'm a bit wary to hold your hand too much. No offense, but I'm not sure whether you have the know-how and experience to take care of a server that can be reached (and potentially abused) from basically everywhere in the world. It may be a better idea to move your WP installations to some kind of hosting service and gain more knowledge and experience.

Comment: Thanks but I have to solve this. Info is in the post and my answers. Could you give me some commands to test your solution? I have backups, so don't worry about it.

Comment: @rem3on, your question was kind-of answered in context of PHP and Curl. Your problem is not with either of them but with broken APT packages due to failed distro upgrade. You probably need to check status of your packages with `dpkg -l 'php*'`, remove old packages with `sudo apt-get remove PACKAGE_NAME` and then install them with `sudo apt-get install PACKAGE_NAME`. (you might need to `sudo dpkg --purge PKG` and `sudo apt-get clean` if removing doesn't work) Refer to `man apt`, `man apt-get`, `man dpkg` and google how to fix broken packages.

Comment: If you are unable to fix the problem on your own, I suggest creating a new question, something like "APT package is broken due to a competing one" with tags such as `package-management apt 20.04`. Include output of `sudo apt-get check` (check apt status), `sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r` (status of broken packages), `sudo dpkg -l 'php*'` (status of php-related packages), `sudo dpkg --get-selections`, `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` (fix missing pkg, won't actually fix your problem) and `sudo apt-get install -f` (autofix broken - likely won't work either), alongside your own manual fix attempts.

Comment: Checking out  Henning Kockerbeck's answer again, I ran sudo apt-get purge php7.4-common and then ''sudo apt install php php-cli php-fpm php-json php-common php-mysql php-zip php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath'' And, the problem has been solved, I don't get curl is missing error now. Though this problem is solved I have to make sure that there is no mess in the server, what can I do?